# Using wireless interface in guest OS with bridged network in VMware fusion 3

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vmware-fusion

I'm running Ubuntu in Snow Leopard with VMware fusion 3, and I want to be able to access the wireless network on eth1 within Ubuntu so I can run tools like aircrack-ng. However, the bridged network that VMware sets up connects my Airport interface in Mac to the wired interface eth0 in Ubuntu. How do I set it up so that the Airport interface is connected to the wireless interface eth1 in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unforunatley what your descrbing is not possible. Vmware can ONLY pass USB devices from the host to the guestOS. The wifi card in your mac is a pci device, and cannot be passed thru to your guestOS, ubuntu sees eth0 as a real hardware nic, though in reality it's vmware bridging your hosts connection and creating a virtual device that ubuntu thinks is real.

If you really want to use wifi in a VM to try aircrack and the like then you will have to buy a compatible USB wifi device ( search the backtrack Linux distro forums for an idea of supported hardware ) and you will be able to pass it thru to your guestOS with no issues.

Hope this helps :)